# mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at - debian bullseye

Tags: mariadb, debian, bullseye

I've upgraded my server from stretch to buster and then to bullseye and from this time i have some problems with mariadb server which is restarting often. While is restarting my emails doesnt work cuz of looking for virtual table etc...

mariadb version is

```
mariadb -v
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 9135
Server version: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log Debian 11
```

then in syslog i can see this

```
cat /var/log/syslog |grep "mariadb.service"

Aug 19 10:34:45 srv systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 19 10:34:50 srv systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 401.
```

dont know how to resolve this problem, maybe i should reinstall mariadb and purge before all packets of mariadb and mysql?

mariadb is restarting 6-10 times in one hour

in syslog i can see this interesting

```
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: 2022-08-19 10:34:45 11917 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Page old data size 15870 new data size 8280, page old max ins size 36 new max ins size 7626
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: 220819 10:34:45 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: Server version: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: key_buffer_size=792723456
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: read_buffer_size=131072
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: max_used_connections=15
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: max_threads=2002
Aug 19 10:34:45 srv mariadbd[22091]: thread_count=12
```